# How to read the last n characters of a txt file, without using stdio.h?

Tags: c, system-calls

I am trying to read the last n-amount of digits from a text file without using the stdio.h function calls. I am unsure on how to do this as I am unable to use fseek without using stdio.h and I am not familiar with system calls. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {

    int fd;
    char buf[200];

    fd = open("logfile.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open the file.\n");
        exit(1); }

    read(fd, buf, 200);

    close(fd);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use stdio.h?

Comment: It looks like what you want to use is [`lseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html).

Comment: If I see the error message `Couldn't open the file.`, I immediately ask 2 questions.  Which file?  Why not?  Your error message should include both of those details.  That is easily accomplished with `perror("logfile.txt")`.  A third question that can come up is "which program?"  Some systems provide easy wrappers for that as well, eg `err(EXIT_FAILURE, "logfile.txt")`

Comment: @dedecos It's a homework assignment to teach us about system calls

Comment: Unrelated question: What OS are you running (if Linux, what distribution)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `lseek`. Here's the prototype:

```
off_t lseek(int fd, off_t offset, int whence);
```

Here's how you can integrate it into your code:

```
lseek(fd, -200, SEEK_END);
read(fd, buf, 200);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for variety:

```
struct stat sb;

int fd = open( filename, O_RDONLY );
fstat( fd, &sb );
pread( fd, buf, 200, sb.st_size - 200 );
```

Note that `lseek()` then `read()` is not atomic, so if more than one thread is accessing the file descriptor, you'll have a race condition.  `pread()` is atomic.